# Filter people from Django model using birth date

Tags: python, django, filter, date

I have this model:

```
class People(models.Model):
    """
    People model
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    birth_date = models.DateField()
```

and I want to filter all people with an age given as parameter, example:

```
min_age = 24
# Filter people older than  ´min_age´
people = People.objects.filter(birth_date__lte = (#something here to filter with age))
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to check against a `datetime.date` that is the maximum allowed birth date: anyone born after that day will be younger than the min age:

```
from datetime import date

min_age = 24
max_date = date.today()
try:
    max_date = max_date.replace(year=max_date.year - min_age)
except ValueError: # 29th of february and not a leap year
    assert max_date.month == 2 and max_date.day == 29
    max_date = max_date.replace(year=max_date.year - min_age, month=2, day=28)
people = People.objects.filter(birth_date__lte=max_date)
```

Comment: That's one good way to do, but to work properly when replacing year on max_date, it must be assigned to max_date with the new value:

`max_date = max_date.replace(year=max_date.year - min_age)`

or max_date will continue storing `date.today()` value.
thanks for your answer.

Comment: Wow I feel so stupid now :/ Actually pulled that example from my own source code, so much for testing...